# Is there a Java function for computing the Gini coefficient?

Tags: java

I was wondering whether there is a Java function, either built-in to Java, or in an "offical" library such as [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/), which computes the Gini coefficient.

From Wikipedia → [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient):

> In economics, the Gini coefficient, sometimes called the Gini index or Gini ratio, is a measure of statistical dispersion intended to represent the income or wealth distribution of a nation's residents, and is the most commonly used measurement of inequality.

Comment: apache spark had gini impurity, which i had doubt if its what you need. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/impurity/Gini.html generally speaking, this question asking for library suggestion does not align with stsckoverflow question guideline.

Comment: i do curious why didnt you try to implement the formula yourself? it doesnt seem it had deferentiation or integration magic in it.

Comment: @BagusTesa Do you have a suggestion about where I should ask such a library related question?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of one. But then writing one is pretty trivial!

```
double gini(List<Double> values) {
    double sumOfDifference = values.stream()
        .flatMapToDouble(v1 -> values.stream().mapToDouble(v2 -> Math.abs(v1 - v2))).sum();
    double mean = values.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).average().getAsDouble();
    return sumOfDifference / (2 * values.size() * values.size() * mean);
}
```